# Comparing two strings and return the common characters between them?

Tags: javascript, string, function, variables, dom

I started off with this:

```
var goalWord = ""; // this and userWord are populated with words from an array I haven't listed here

var userWord = "";

function countCorrectCharacters(userWord, goalWord){
  var compareNum = 0;
    var common = document.createElement('common');
    div.innerHTML = "testing";
    common.style.color = 'red';
    common.setAttribute('class', 'myclass');
    document.bottom-screen.appendChild(common);
    document.body.appendChild(common);
  var check = Math.min(userWord.length, goalWord.length);
  for (var i = 0; i < check; i++) {
    if (userWord.charAt(i) == goalWord.charAt(i))
    compareNum++;
 }
 return compareNum;
}

countCorrectCharacters(userWord, goalWord);
```

But for the life of me I can't tell if it's working. I'm pretty iffy on manipulating DOM elements, so that might be the problem but I'm not sure sure.

Comment: Why can't you tell if it is working? What is preventing that?

Answer (score 1):

The function to count the common characters between the two strings works. Your DOM manipulation isn't working. You should separate these things, as they are different concerns.

```js
function countCommonCharacters(userWord, goalWord){
  var compareNum = 0;    
  var check = Math.min(userWord.length, goalWord.length);
  for (var i = 0; i < check; i++) {
    if (userWord.charAt(i) == goalWord.charAt(i))
    compareNum++;
  }
  return compareNum;
}

function showResult(result) {
  var div = document.createElement('div');
  div.innerHTML = result;
  div.style.color = 'red';
  document.body.appendChild(div);
}

var goalWord = "12345678";
var userWord = "02345000";
var result = countCommonCharacters(userWord, goalWord);
showResult(result);
```

Comment: I'm not seeing anything :( But I'll keep trying. Thanks for rearranging the code, it looks much better than what I had.

Comment: What do you mean you are not seeing anything? If you run the code snippet above (dark blue button) you should see a red "4".

Comment: Sorry, I meant in my browser I'm not seeing anything.

Comment: It works in Chrome, Firefox, and Edge. What browser are you using?

Comment: Chrome. I'll try Firefox.